# Unix: Group by with custom function

Tags: bash, unix

My text file looks like this

```
id, key, value
i1, k1, v1
i1, k2, v2
i1, k2, v3
```

I need to operate `group by` on `<id, key>` and have a custom function which say concats all values. So resulting output looks like

```
id, key, value
i1, k1, v1
i1, k2, v2||v3
```

How can we achieve this in unix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have awk:

```
awk -F, '{k=$1FS$2;a[k]=(k in a)?a[k]"||"$3:$3}END{for(x in a)print x FS a[x]}' file
id, key, value
i1, k1, v1
i1, k2, v2|| v3
```

Comment: Thanks @Kent. Is there anything like lambda function in awk/unix, where we don't have to explicitly handle change in key etc.